# undetected_chromedriver - is throwing TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to open chrome in headless mode with undetected_chromedriver (version='3.4.6') however throwing `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'` error. Any suggestions please

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("--password-store=basic")
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs",
    {
        "credentials_enable_service": False,
        "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
    }, )
driver = Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue with the module:

- GitHub Issue Link: [#1200 TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1200)